# AMP: how to do a Survey in CSS without using style="width"?

Tags: html, css, survey, amp-html

I have a progress bar from a survey made of CSS and inside of the HTML tag I have a `style="width"` so I don't need to have classes like `.width-99 { width: 99%;}` for all the values.

Now, I have to make an amp version of it and I wanted to know if there is another way to do a progress bar without the `.width-99 { width: 99%;}` thing. Even because my code should be as lean as possible.

My other option is to disable it in AMP version, but it's also not ideal.

My code:

```css
.survey {
 font-size: 1.9rem;
}

.survey-bar {
 display: inline-block;

 width: 91%;
 height: 3.8rem;

 border-radius: 4px;

 background: #EBEBEB;
}

.results {
 display: flex;

 margin-top: .5rem;

 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}


.results span {
 display: inline-block;

 height: 3.8rem;

 border-radius: 4px;

 background: #777;
}

.results span.winner {
 display: flex;

 align-items: center;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* 'tick' icon */
.results span.winner:before {
 padding-right: .5rem;

 font-family: 'icomoon';
 font-size: 2.7rem;
 color: #FFF;

 content: '\e90e';
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
    15%
    <div class="survey-bar">
        <span style="width: 15%"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>It was popularised in the 1960s</p>
<div class="results">
    80%
    <div class="survey-bar">
        <span style="width: 80%" class="winner"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages</p>
<div class="results">
    5%
    <div class="survey-bar">
        <span style="width: 5%"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:** AMP means Accelerated Mobile Pages.

Some rules:

- I have to put all CSS of the page inline
- I can only use one CSS inline in all the page

Website without AMP: [LINK](http://g1.globo.com/mundo/noticia/2016/11/na-grecia-obama-defende-europa-unida-e-debate-sobre-desigualdade.html)

AMP version: [LINK](http://g1.globo.com/mundo/noticia/2016/11/na-grecia-obama-defende-europa-unida-e-debate-sobre-desigualdade.amp)

Comment: Why can't you use inline css? If you can update the class name, you can update an inline style value.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid `style="width: …"`? Also, what do you mean by "amp version"?

Comment: @SeinopSys perhaps AMP-HTML..?

Comment: AMP means Accelerated Mobile Pages. If I try to validate my code with one inline CSS, I cannot pass the validation.

Comment: That's awful validation. Inline CSS isn't inherently bad, you shouldn't let a tool tell you to not use inline CSS at all. It has its uses, and if not overused - like in your case - it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you guys knew the AMP. I made an edit in the post.

Comment: @SeinopSys is right, inline CSS isn't always bad, and in the scenario you described it would be leaner than attempting to create 100x style rules. Is passing validation critical to the project? Or can it be ignored in this instance?

Comment: @Dre I cannot I find nothing else about it, only that it's not allowed. I'm trying to search this on google or contact someone expert in it, when I find a way to do so I'll update this question with an answer (if I get one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [this open issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3578) on Github and is really forbidden to use more than one inline CSS per page.

So, in my case, I'm going to remove all styles and only stay with the texts.